# __weak seemingly retains the object

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Objective-C weak properties should point to nil if the object gets deallocated, but in this case weak properties seem to retain the object. Consider the case:

```
@interface SillyObject : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger val;

-(void)printVal;

@end

@implementation SillyObject

-(void)printVal
{
  NSLog(@"%d", self.val);
}

@end

-(void)saveReference
{
  SillyObject* s = [SillyObject new];
  s.val = 100;

  [[ObjectCache sharedInstance] addWeakRef:s callback:^(NSString* junk) {
    [s printVal];
  }];
}
```

callSillyObjectBlocks loops over all the objects added to the cache and calls the correspondending blocks (see below)

```
-(void)callDeadObject
{
  [self saveReference];
  [[ObjectCache sharedInstance] callSillyObjectBlocks];
}
```

Now saveReference exits and the SillyObject should be deallocated, but it doesn't and the weak reference is not nil.

The relevant implementation details of the cache:

```
typedef void (^Callback)(NSString* junk);

@interface CacheSlot : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) Callback callback;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id source;
// More irrelevant properties.

-(instancetype)initWithRef:(__weak id)obj callback:(Callback)cb;

@end

@implementation CacheSlot

@synthesize callback, source;

-(instancetype)initWithRef:(__weak id)obj callback:(Callback)cb
{
  self = [super init];
  if(self)
  {
    self.callback = cb;
    self.source = obj;
  }
  return self;
}

@end

@interface ObjectCache()

// This array contains CacheSlot objects
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* savedObjects;
@end

// Implementation.
-(void)addWeakRef:(id)obj callback:(Callback)block
{
  __weak id src = obj;
  [self.savedObjects addObject:[[CacheSlot alloc] initWithRef:src callback:block]];
}

-(void)callSillyObjectBlocks
{
  for(CacheSlot* slot in self.savedObjects)
  {
    if(slot.source)
    {
      slot.callback(@"Whatever!");
    }
    else
    {
      // Remove the slot from cache
    }
  }
}
```

Calling saveReference initially should create a temporary object which gets deallocated as soon as the function exits (which it does if I call addWeakRef:nil instead).

After calling saveReference I run callSillyObjectBlocks and the added object's corresponding block should not be called, but it gets called with the object's value.
Output:

```
100
```

Comment: Note that reading a weak variable may retain and autorelease the object. You may need to add an autorelease pool to clean up those references and allow the object to die.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you have a block that references a variable from outside the block, you need to declare it as *weak* as well. Otherwise you get a strong reference. So it should be:

```
-(void)saveReference
{
  SillyObject* s = [SillyObject new];
  s.val = 100;
  SillyObject * __weak weakSilly = s;

  [[ObjectCache sharedInstance] addWeakRef:s callback:^(NSString* junk) {
    [weakSilly printVal];
  }];
}
```

At the same time you could simplify your code by removing `__weak` from a few other locations as they affect method arguments only that will no retain an instance for a relevant time:

```
-(instancetype)initWithRef:(id)obj callback:(Callback)cb {
    ...
}

-(void)addWeakRef:(id)obj callback:(Callback)block
{
  [self.savedObjects addObject:[[CacheSlot alloc] initWithRef:obj callback:block]];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, although in an usability way this is terrible :( If I'm using the cache and want to add self to the object cache with a corresponding block, I wouldn't want to exchange self with weakSelf in every line of the block. But at the moment I can't think of a workaround for this.

Comment: You might want to think about the design of your cache. As it currently stands, you add two references for each cached instance: one direct reference (instance variable *source*) and one indirect reference (via the *callback* instance variable and the associated block). One could also image that all cached instance implement a common *CacheCallback* protocol. Then you could get rid of the *callback* instance variable and all associated problems.

Comment: You are right, however using blocks would have been more convenient than than making the class conform to the protocol every time.